# How to execute the main thread code block immediately after the end of the sub thread code block？

Tags: grand-central-dispatch

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.xxx.child", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSLog(@"xxx");
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"yyy");
        });
    });
}
```

I hope print "xxx","yyy","xxx","yyy"...

How to modify?

Comment: Also, unrelated to the immediate task at hand, you should be careful of dispatching a large number of concurrent tasks (especially if you decide you want to make one wait for the other). This is known as thread explosion. With 20 tasks it's not a deal-breaker, but if it exceeds 64 concurrent tasks with that QoS, you’ll start to encounter problems. Let's not worry about that right now, but just a FYI to be very careful with the pattern in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems:

First, you're using `dispatch_async()`. This function queues a block of code to execute *asynchronously* on some other thread.

This has two important implications:

- The execution of the code block is unpredictable; it may execute before, concurrently, or after the rest of the code that queued it.
- If `queue` is a *concurrent* queue (the default), then the other 19 blocks may also execute concurrently; in fact, all 20 blocks could be running at the same time, with no guarantee of order.

To guarantee that you print "xxx","yyy","xxx","yyy", ... you must ensure that the initial blocks all execute **sequentially**, and that each sub-block executes **synchronously**.

So your code needs to look like this:

```
// `queue` must be created as a serial queue
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("xxxs",DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSLog(@"xxx");
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"yyy");
        });
    });
}
```

The loop will immediately create and queue 20 blocks of code, adding them to the serial `queue` in order. Because `queue` is serial, only one block on the queue will execute at a time, and the second queued block won't start until the first has finished.

When the first block executes, it prints "xxx" then **synchronously** queues a block to run on the main thread. A synchronous call halts the thread (the first block) until that sub-block has executed on the main thread.

Once the "yyy" block finishes, the `dispatch_sync` call returns and the first block resumes execution and exits. The second block on `queue` starts to run and the whole thing repeats until all of the blocks have executed.

Having said all of that, because you want all of this code to execute sequentially, there's really no advantage to creating a serial queue and adding individual blocks. This code does the exact same thing and is much simpler:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        NSLog(@"xxx");
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"yyy");
        });
    }
});
```

I hope that helps your understanding of queues and synchronous vs. asynchronous dispatch calls.

Answer (score 0):

When you suggest that you don’t want to see the second “xxx” before you see the first “yyy”, that’s effectively saying that you really don’t want them to run concurrently. The definition of “concurrent” is that you would like to see the second task start before the first task finishes (i.e., to see the second “xxx” before you see the first “yyy”). The only way to achieve the strict “xxx”, “yyy”, “xxx”, “yyy”, ..., print order, as James has pointed out, is to not have the tasks run concurrently. And the slower that these background tasks are, the greater the performance penalty you will experience by not running them concurrently.

The real answer to the question is “consider refactoring your code so that it doesn’t matter what order the parallel tasks finish; you will achieve better performance than slowing it down to run these tasks sequentially.” But until you give us actual example of what you're trying to do, it’s hard to advise you further.